# TYPO3 RealURL spaceCharacter

Tags: typo3, realurl

I am upgrading a site from 6.2 LTS to 7.6 LTS. In the 6.2 installation the RealURL spaceCharacter was not configured so the default, underscore, was used. In 7.6 with the same configuration a hyphen is used. I have now set the spaceCharacter to underscore (see below) but this has no effect.

I am mystified also that I cannot find the file class.tx_realurl_advanced.php in the RealURL 2.2.1 installation.

```
        'pagePath' => array(
            'spaceCharacter' => '_',
            'type' => 'user',
            'userFunc' => 'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
            'expireDays' => 3,
            'disablePathCache' => '1',
        ),
```

What have I done wrong?
Graham

Answer (score 1):

`pagePath` has no option `spaceCharacter` anymore:
https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Configuration-reference#pagepath

In EXT:realurl/Classes/Configuration/ConfigurationReader.php this block can be found:

```
protected $defaultValues = array(
    'cache/banUrlsRegExp' => '/tx_solr|tx_indexedsearch|tx_kesearch|(?:^|\?|&)q=/',
    'cache/ignoredGetParametersRegExp' => '/^(?:gclid|utm_[a-z]+|pk_campaign|pk_kwd|TSFE_ADMIN_PANEL.*)$/',
    'fileName/acceptHTMLsuffix' => TRUE,
    'fileName/defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => FALSE,
    'init/appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile,redirect[301]',
    'init/defaultLanguageUid' => 0,
    'init/emptySegmentValue' => '',
    'pagePath/spaceCharacter' => '-', // undocumented & deprecated!
);
```

But I seems to be supportet when I have a look in the code. Maybe you have to clear all tx_realurl_* tables.

And last `class.tx_realurl_advanced.php` is gone.

You can find the documentation for EXT:realurl 2 here:
https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice Heinz.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice Heinz.
Part of my problem was that the extension manual on the TYPO3 repository page was for v1.13.7 whilst the software was v2.2.1. I should have spotted that!
However, as you pointed out, the pagePath/spaceCharacter feature was still there but undocumented. So I set it to underscore - but I still got hyphens. 
After a good deal of frustration I realised that none of the methods I was using to clear the RealURL cache (TYPO3 backend, install tool and RealURL module) was doing the job - though the RealURL module reported the entries as having gone. Eventually I truncated the database tables and my underscores re-appeared.